# Positions of reporting verb in direct/indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

This is the sentence: our coach said that our captain was good at making decisions.

Can I use for direct speech: Said our coach, "our captain is good at making decision."

Is it correct?

Comment: You're not going to find that word order in many newspapers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. You can frame it in four different ways. These are not stringent rules but give a general idea.

> Starting with reporting verb

**Said our coach**, "our captain is good at making decisions."

> Putting it at the end

" Our captain is good at making decisions," **the coach said**.

> After subject at the beginning of the sentence

**Our coach said**, "our captain is good at making decisions."

> In this form (I don't know what it is called)

" Our captain is good at making decisions," **said the coach**.

Comment: You can also stick the attribution several places inside the direct quote. For example: "Our captain," the coach said, "is good at making decisions."

Comment: @Clare Fixed the error. Nice catch. I couldn't detect any difference, even though I proofread it once.

Answer (score -2):

Uh… no. Direct speech doesn’t change what was said.

The original sentence looks as though it is indirect reported speech, in which case all that can really be said of it is that however clear the meaning appears, what is written is not necessarily what was said.

Grammatically or semantically it’s fine to say ‘Said our coach, "our captain is good at making decision"’ but how could that have anything to do with direct speech, please?

Comment: Your answer is very incoherent. Can you give some examples of what you're trying to say?

Comment: Thanks, XPMai, and in your book does *coherent* mean something like *hanging together* or *forming a unified whole* or *logically consistent* or what, please?
I suggested three things, which remain *coherent*, both individually and collectively.
What makes anything direct speech is that what was said is not changed. ‘Plain’ direct speech is what you see in books, plays or filmscripts: exactly what is to be said.
Direct 'reported' speech starts with exactly exactly the same words, perhaps dropping for brevity, clarity or relevance. Still, nothing may be added or altered.

Is that clearer?

Comment: XPMai The original is clearly indirect reported speech. Obviously not what the coach actually said, it makes no claim to accuracy, instead giving one of too many possible interpretations.
Do you see no difference between direct *our coach said: “Our captain is good at making decisions”* and indirect *our coach said (that) our captain was good at making decisions*? What is written is exactly what was said.
Do you see *indirect* can always be derived from *direct*, by definition of *direct* but the opposite is never certain?

Comment: XPMai , *Direct* might sometimes be derived from *indirect* but by definition of *indirect*, that involves working backwards with no certain starting point? What is written cannot necessarily bewhat was said.
It’s fine to say *Said our coach: “Our captain is good at making decisions*’ but how could you demonstrate that was truly what the coach said, based on the indirect report?